# Split single text cell into multiple rows with replicate other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split single column values into multiple rows, the split text seems to be possible for me, but I also want the new rows were created based on another column values.

```
| Order_id|  Customer| Product |
----------------------------------------------
| 1       |  John    | table, chair, cabinet |
| 2       |  Bob     | table, chair  |
| 3       |  Dylan   | cabinet |
```

my desired result will look like:

```
| Order_id|  Customer| Product |
----------------------------------------------
| 1       |  John    | table |
| 1       |  John    | chair |
| 1       |  John    | cabinet |
| 2       |  Bob     | table |
| 2       |  Bob     | chair |
| 3       |  Dylan   | cabinet |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not working with SQL Server +12 then the `XML` nodes method might be helpful.

```
select 
       Order_id, Customer,
       ltrim( P.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))  Product
from
(
       select Order_id, Customer,
              cast('<X>'+replace(Product , ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' as xml) Product
       from table
)a cross apply Product.nodes ('/X') as Product(P)
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you are using SQL server 2016 and above you can use [SPLIT_STRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function.
<kbd>**[See working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab48f/1/0)**</kbd>

```
SELECT Order_Id, Customer, value  
FROM tblOrder
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Product, ',');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a user-defined [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) as one of the SQL functions mentioned in the referred resource, you can build your SQL SELECT statement as follows

```
select
    Order_id, Customer, p.val as Product
from MyOrders o
cross apply dbo.Split(o.Product, ',') p
```